# changed my wordpress url from http to https and now admin panel is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https

i changed the URL from HTTP to HTTP'S and the moment i did it my admin panel stopped working add the line in WP-config site URL and all but still not working 
now i don't what do please help me out

Answer (score 1):

open your `functions.php` in your `theme` directory and put the following lines in

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://yourdomain.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://yourdomain.com' );
```

after that - try to reload a couple of times your site
(you should remove those lines - if it was successful)

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should fix in the `functions.php`. I strongly suggest that you use the following:

- Go to your phpmyadmin, mysql workbench or a equivalent control panel where       you can edit your database.
- Go to your wordpress database
- Go to the `wp_options` table
- Change the `siteurl` and `home` record back to a working url
- Save your changes

This way you are 99.9% sure that the changes are commited.

If you do not have access to the control panel, you can use the `functions.php` equivalent as sintakonte suggested, or ask your database administrator.

**Be sure to check if the record has updated in the database.**